# jsPlumb translate to toom

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

There is a good chapter in the documentation for jsPlumb for implementing the zoom feature [Doku](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/zooming.html). But there is nothing written about horizontal and vertical translation in addition.

This is basically what happens when you do a 75% zoom:

```
$("#container").css({
  "-webkit-transform":"scale(0.75)",
  "-moz-transform":"scale(0.75)",
  "-ms-transform":"scale(0.75)",
  "-o-transform":"scale(0.75)",
  "transform":"scale(0.75)"
});
```

What I need here is a hint how to start with the addition of the translate?

Comment: What *is* that `toom` in the title?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it but have you tried

```
$("#container").css({
  "-webkit-transform-origin":"75% 75%",
  "-moz-transform-origin":"75% 75%",
  "-ms-transform-origin":"75% 75%",
  "-o-ttransform-origin":"75% 75%",
  "transform-origin":"75% 75%"
});
```